# Adding email attachment name to my report Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

With the below code I'm getting an error when I try to add an attachment file name to the report. Perhaps it is the syntax?

The error is occurring at `Report = Report & currentItem.Attachments.FileName` line

The error is "object doesn't support this property or method.

Any ideas?

I am running this code in Outlook,

```
Private Sub GetAllEmailsInFolder(CurrentFolder As Outlook.Folder, Report As String)
    Dim currentItem
    Dim attachment As attachment
    Dim currentMail As MailItem

    Report = Report & "Folder Name: " & CurrentFolder.Name & " (Store: " & CurrentFolder.Store.DisplayName & ")" & vbCrLf

    For Each currentItem In CurrentFolder.Items
        Report = Report & currentItem.Subject
        Report = Report & vbCrLf
        Report = Report & "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
        Report = Report & vbCrLf
        Report = Report & currentItem.Attachments.FileName

    Next

End Sub
```

Also, I first run a sub that gets a list of emails:

```
Public Sub GetListOfEmails()
    'On Error GoTo On_Error

    Dim Session As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim Report As String
    Dim Folder As Outlook.Folder

    Set Session = Application.Session

    Set Folder = Application.ActiveExplorer.CurrentFolder

    Call GetAllEmailsInFolder(Folder, Report)

    Dim retValue As Boolean
    retValue = CreateReportAsEmail("List of Emails", Report)

Exiting:
        Set Session = Nothing
        Exit Sub
On_Error:
    MsgBox "error=" & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume Exiting

End Sub
```

Then here is the sub I use to create the report in the form of an email I want to copy into excel.

```
Public Function CreateReportAsEmail(Title As String, Report As String)
    'On Error GoTo On_Error

    Dim Session As Outlook.NameSpace
    Dim mail As MailItem
    Dim MyAddress As AddressEntry
    Dim Inbox As Outlook.Folder

    CreateReportAsEmail = True

    Set Session = Application.Session
    Set Inbox = Session.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    Set mail = Inbox.Items.Add("IPM.Mail")

    Set MyAddress = Session.CurrentUser.AddressEntry
    mail.Recipients.Add (MyAddress.Address)
    mail.Recipients.ResolveAll

    mail.Subject = Title
    mail.Body = Report

    mail.Save
    mail.Display


Exiting:
        Set Session = Nothing
        Exit Function
On_Error:
    CreateReportAsEmail = False
    MsgBox "error=" & Err.Number & " " & Err.Description
    Resume Exiting

End Function
```

Comment: The `Attachments` collection doesn't have a filename property - each individual `Attachment` does

Comment: @BigBen oh I see, so perhaps I need to create a function to extract the attachment file name? I'll be using the report for metrics. There are really only a few different kinds of attachments this inbox receives. I want to know they breakdown on a monthly basis

Comment: You could loop through the `Attachments` collection and extract the filename from each individual attachment.

Comment: @BigBen anyway you have time to draw that up real quick? I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. ideally the name for each attachment is what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- The [`Attachments`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachments) collection does not have a `Filename` property, but each *individual* `Attachment` does. Add an additional loop through the `Attachments` collection.
- `GetAllEmailsInFolder` should be a `Function` returning a `String`. A `Sub` does something; a `Function` *returns* something.
- `GetAllEmailsInFolder` assumes that all the items within `CurrentFolder` are `MailItem`s, which might *not* be the case.
- Use a different variable name than `attachment` for each `Attachment`. Same goes for `Folder`, `Session`...

Untested, but something like this:

```
Private Function GetAllEmailsInFolder(CurrentFolder As Outlook.Folder) As String
    Dim currentItem As Object
    Dim myAttachment As Attachment
    Dim Report as String

    Report = Report & "Folder Name: " & CurrentFolder.Name & " (Store: " & CurrentFolder.Store.DisplayName & ")" & vbCrLf

    For Each currentItem In CurrentFolder.Items
        If TypeOf currentItem Is Outlook.MailItem Then
            Report = Report & currentItem.Subject
            Report = Report & vbCrLf
            Report = Report & "----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------"
            Report = Report & vbCrLf
            For Each myAttachment in currentItem.Attachments
                Report = Report & myAttachment.Filename ' and add formatting inbetween as needed
            Next myAttachment
        End If
    Next currentItem

    GetAllEmailsInFolder = Report
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

*Here is quick Example, you may need to adjust little on how it displays on email.*

```
    For Each currentItem In CurrentFolder.Items
        Report = Report & currentItem.Subject
        Report = Report & vbCrLf
        Report = Report & "--------------------------------------------------------"
        Report = Report & vbCrLf
'        Report = Report & currentItem.Attachments.FileName

        For Each attachment In currentItem.Attachments
            Debug.Print attachment.FileName
            Report = Report & attachment.FileName
        Next

    Next
```

*[MSDN Attachment Object (Outlook)](http://%20https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.attachment)*

Comment: Sorry to add what is essentially the same answer at its core, but I had to point out additional issues and was in the middle of drawing it up :)

Comment: @BigBen its cool +1v, that's good [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52673114/4539709)